# AlarmManager android call specific method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I Would like to set Alarmmanager that start after 30 second an execute a specific method..

For example:

//In this alarm i want to call SpecificMehtod();

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AutoStartUp.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent1, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pintent);//ripeto l'alarm ogni 24 ore



public void SpecificMethod(){
   //Some code here
}
```

Sorry for my english =)

Comment: good luck, let us know if you run into any issues

Answer (score 0):

You can do the intent, add an extra to it, and send the user to the `AutoStartUp` activity:

```
intent.putExtra("name","specificMethod");
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the `AutoStartUp` activity, you can start the method by checking the extra:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if(i.getStringExtra("name").equals("specificMethod")){
  specificMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create broadcast Reciever and set with alarm manager

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AutoStartUp.class);   
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),10*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

Her is your broadcast recevier class

```
public class AutoStartUp extends BroadcastReceiver{


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       specificMethod();

}
```

}

Don't forget to register it mainfest

```
<receiver android:name=".AutoStartUp"
                      android:enabled="true"
                    > 
            </receiver>
```